# Parametric form equation and plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find in parametric form the equations for all lines passing through $(1, 1, 1)$ and lying in the plane $x + 2y − z = 2$.

How I approached it I turned plane equation into parametric form, then substracted it from to point $(1, 1, 1)$. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parametric form for the plane $(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+s\cdot d_1+t\cdot d_2$ where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are vectors, then a parametric form for such a line is $$(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+t(\cos(v)\cdot d_1+\sin(v)\cdot d_2)$$

where $v$ determines which of those lines the parametric form represents.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $(1,1,1)$ is in the plane. We take any vector parallel to the plane, and this must lie in $x+2y-z=0$ and therefore have form $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1+2\lambda_2)$. So the equation of the line is $(1,1,1) + t(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1+2\lambda_2)$.